# Can I get time & distance from OSM2PO without loading data into PostgreSQL?

Tags: routing, osm2po

Can I get time and distance from OSM2PO routing without loading the data into PostgreSQL? I've seen the answer regarding matching IDs with the DB, but I need to do this using only the OSM2PO service.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using SOAP or HTTP/GET via JavaScript/AJAX?
In both cases you get all segments where each segment contains the distance and time values. All you have to do is to add those values.

Comment: Thanks Carsten. What do I need to do to get those values? I'm using HTTP/GET. I used format=geojson but did not see distance/time values. Do I need to update my version of OSM2PO?

Comment: Awesome, so it was that I had an older version of OSM2PO. The new version has alot more detail in the geojson format. One last question. What are the units for the distance/time? Carsten OSM2PO is an awesome product. Keep up the great work my friend!

Comment: Time[h] and Distance[km]